# KOMA not changing page sizes in the mid of the document

Tags: koma-script

I am trying to change pagesize using KOMA but not able to

```
\usepackage[paper=A4]{typearea}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{geometry}
\begin{document}

\KOMAoptions{paper=2.5in:6.0in,DIV=1}
\recalctypearea
"POTRAIT"

\KOMAoptions{paper=6in:2.5in,DIV=1}
\recalctypearea
"LANDSCAPE"

\end{document}
```

Using KOMA i am trying to setup two page sizes `2.5in:6.0in` and `6in:2.5in`.

But the output pdf shows two pages of size `2.5in:6.0in` no `6in:2.5in`.

[image]

**SOLUTION1: WHICH I FOUND WORKING (ALSO I AM ADDING PAGENUMBER)**

Note:

```
1) use \documentclass[version=3.21]{scrartcl}
2) mention page size as width:height
3) no need of landscape



\documentclass[version=3.21]{scrartcl}
% this is required for pagenumber and also KOMAoptions to work
\usepackage[automark,headsepline,footsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
% the above both are required to show page number 

\usepackage
  [showframe]% to show the page layout
  {geometry}

\begin{document}

\KOMAoptions{paper=2.5in:6.0in,DIV=calc}
 % widht:height
\recalctypearea
\newgeometry{layoutwidth = 2.5in,layoutheight = 6.0in,left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,footskip=1mm}
"POTRAIT"

\KOMAoptions{paper=6in:2.5in,DIV=calc}
% here widht:height mention 6in:2.5in instead of 2.5:6in
\recalctypearea
\newgeometry{layoutwidth =6in,layoutheight = 2.5in,left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,footskip=1mm}
"LANDSCAPE"

\end{document}
```

The output is (i also wanted to add the page number at the bottom. So newgeometry is used to reset the margins

[image]

**SOLUTION2: WHICH I FOUND WORKING (ALSO I AM ADDING PAGENUMBER)**

Here irrespective of widht:height it will show portrait. We have to specifically mention portrait or landscape. Recently i have made a spell mistake i was using `potrait` instead of `portrait` and i thought its not working.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\begin{document}

    \KOMAoptions{paper=432pt:566.36717pt,paper=portrait}
    \recalctypearea
    \newgeometry{layoutwidth = 432pt,layoutheight = 566.36717pt,left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm, bottom=0mm,footskip=1mm}
    POTRAIT

    \KOMAoptions{paper=432pt:226.15027pt,paper=landscape}
    \recalctypearea
    \newgeometry{layoutwidth = 432pt,layoutheight = 226.15027pt,left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm, bottom=0mm,footskip=1mm}
    LANDSCAPE

    \KOMAoptions{paper=432pt:566.36717pt,paper=portrait}
    \recalctypearea
    \newgeometry{layoutwidth = 432pt,layoutheight = 566.36717pt,left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm, bottom=0mm,footskip=1mm}
    EXPECTING SAME POTRAIT

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately your example does not compile because you omitted to show the `\documentclass` declaration with options that you may have set for KOMAscript.

Note:

- KOMAScript documentation says that an explicit loading of the `typearea` package is not necessary; it also notes that it is not advised, in general, to use `typearea` functionality together with the `geometry` package. If this is desired,
  however, there is the `usegeometry=true` option for the KOMAscript class declaration.
- Why set `paper=A4` at all, if you don't need it?
- A `DIV` of `1` would result in a very "bad" dividing of the page; indeed, typearea warns about this very low `DIV` value.

A solution to your question that sets the portrait size first and then simply switches to landscape orientation could be:

```
\documentclass[pagesize, usegeometry=true]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{pdfpages}  %%although it is not needed for your example
\usepackage{geometry}
\begin{document}

\KOMAoptions{paper=2.5in:6.0in,DIV=1}
\recalctypearea
"PORTRAIT"

\KOMAoptions{paper=landscape}
\recalctypearea
"LANDSCAPE"

\end{document}
```

Comment: I have tried `\KOMAoptions{paper=6in:2.5in,DIV=1}` instead of `\KOMAoptions{paper=landscape}` . It again shows both the pages as `2.5in:6.0in`. I just want to mention the paper size instead of landscape or portrait because i will have a pdf with variable page sizes

Comment: The way I understand the KOMAscript documentation, the two sizes, e.g. `6in:2.5in` will always be interpreted according to `paper=landscape` or `paper=portrait`, there seems no way around explicitly specifying the orientation when changing page sizes and orientation within a document. See page 49 in the English documentation: [link](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf)

Comment: Thank you for the clear understanding. I wanted to use it by pagesize. so `\KOMAoptions{paper=6in:2.5in,DIV=1,paper=landscape}` will also work then

Comment: what is the difference between `\documentclass[pagesize, usegeometry=true]{scrartcl}` and just `\documentclass{scrartcl}`

Comment: The ´pagesize` option ensures that settings for the page size are passed to the pdfTeX engine, see p. 50-51 in the english documentation. The `usegeometry` option improves the interaction between `typearea` options when the `geometry` package is loaded as well, see pp. 52 and 471 of the doc. IMO there may well be use cases where these options will not make a difference, whereas in other use cases they will.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding  option `paper` there was a change in KOMA-Script version 3.22 (current version is 3.31). Your example would work if you add `version=3.21` to the `typearea` options:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paper=A4,
  version=3.21% <- added, but it is a really old version
]{typearea}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage
  [showframe]% to show the page layout
  {geometry}
\begin{document}

\KOMAoptions{paper=2.5in:6.0in,DIV=calc}
%\KOMAoptions{paper=2.5in:6.0in,DIV=current}% maybe better
"POTRAIT"

\KOMAoptions{paper=6in:2.5in,DIV=calc}
"LANDSCAPE"

\end{document}
```

Note that Option `DIV` results in a recalculation of the typearea. So, if you use the `DIV` key  after the `paper` key in the argument of `\KOMAoptions`, you can remove the additional `\recalctypearea` (does nearly the same as `\KOMAoptions{DIV=last}`).

Note that `DIV=1` is a synonym for `DIV=calc`. But I think you do not want `DIV=calc` for the landscape page.

[image]

Maybe you want to use `DIV=current` for the landscape page?

[image]

Since version 3.22 it depends on the orientation (`portrait` or `landscape`) which value is taken as the height and which as the width. With `paper = portrait`, both `paper=2.5in:6.0in` and `paper=6.0in:2.5in` result in a page with a height of 6.0 inches and a width of 2.5 inches. If you want to switch to `landscape`, you have to use `paper=landscape`! But if the width and height are only exchanged, it is also enough to use `paper=landscape` followed by `DIV=current` or `DIV=last`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paper=A4]{typearea}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[%
  showframe% to show the page layout
]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\KOMAoptions{paper=2.5in:6.0in,DIV=calc}
"POTRAIT"

\KOMAoptions{paper=landscape,DIV=current}
"LANDSCAPE"

\end{document}
```

Comment: I need `pdfpages` for incluing some pdf. Also i want to use `\documentclass{scrartcl}`. Now your solution says `Option clash for package typearea`. How to resolve this

Comment: In your original question there was no documentclass mentioned. The KOMA-Script class `scrartcl` loads package `typearea` automatically, so the options should be set as  global options for the documentclass.

Comment: How to set `paper=A4` and `version=3.21` as global options for while using `\documentclass{scrartcl}`

Comment: `\documentclass[paper=A4,version=3.21]{scrartcl}`. But I would suggest to use the second suggestion (using an uptodate version)  and set the paper orientation explicitly.