# KOMA scripts: Unable to understand the mid document paper size changing behaviour

Tags: pdftex, koma-script, paper-size

I have the following script (first and third page are same. But it shows something different paper size)

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\begin{document}

    \KOMAoptions{paper=432pt:566.36717pt,DIV=calc}
    \recalctypearea
    \newgeometry{layoutwidth = 432pt,layoutheight = 566.36717pt,left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm, bottom=0mm,footskip=1mm}
    POTRAIT

    \KOMAoptions{paper=432pt:226.15027pt,DIV=calc,paper=landscape}
    \recalctypearea
    \newgeometry{layoutwidth = 432pt,layoutheight = 226.15027pt,left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm, bottom=0mm,footskip=1mm}
    LANDSCAPE

    \KOMAoptions{paper=432pt:566.36717pt,DIV=calc}
    \recalctypearea
    \newgeometry{layoutwidth = 432pt,layoutheight = 566.36717pt,left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm, bottom=0mm,footskip=1mm}
    EXPECTING SAME SIZE AND ORIENTATION (POTRAIT) AS FIRST PAGE, BUT DOES NOT WORK

\end{document}
```

This code is not working. The first and last are of same code. Its shows different page size

OUTPUT

[image]

Now i try using `verions=3.21` as per https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/556997/221200

```
\documentclass[version=3.21]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\begin{document}

    \KOMAoptions{paper=432pt:566.36717pt,DIV=calc}
    \recalctypearea
    \newgeometry{layoutwidth = 432pt,layoutheight = 566.36717pt,left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm, bottom=0mm,footskip=1mm}
    POTRAIT

    \KOMAoptions{paper=432pt:226.15027pt,DIV=calc}
    %removed paper=landscape
    \recalctypearea
    \newgeometry{layoutwidth = 432pt,layoutheight = 226.15027pt,left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm, bottom=0mm,footskip=1mm}
    LANDSCAPE

    \KOMAoptions{paper=432pt:566.36717pt,DIV=calc}
    \recalctypearea
    \newgeometry{layoutwidth = 432pt,layoutheight = 566.36717pt,left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm, bottom=0mm,footskip=1mm}
    EXPECTING SAME SIZE AND ORIENTATION (POTRAIT) AS FIRST PAGE AND IT WORKS

\end{document}
```

It works the way the intended to

OUTPUT

[image]

Why the first script is not working well.

**EDIT**

I get an error `! Package scrbase Error: unknown option` paper=potrait'.` for the below code. Whats wrong in this code. It looks same as to the answer of @esdd

```
%%%%%%%  NOT WORKING
\documentclass[usegeometry]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\begin{document}

    \KOMAoptions{paper=432pt:566.36717pt,paper=potrait}
    \recalctypearea
    \newgeometry{layoutwidth = 432pt,layoutheight = 566.36717pt,left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm, bottom=0mm,footskip=1mm}
    POTRAIT

    \KOMAoptions{paper=432pt:226.15027pt,paper=landscape}
    \recalctypearea
    \newgeometry{layoutwidth = 432pt,layoutheight = 226.15027pt,left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm, bottom=0mm,footskip=1mm}
    LANDSCAPE

    \KOMAoptions{paper=432pt:566.36717pt,paper=potrait}
    \recalctypearea
    \newgeometry{layoutwidth = 432pt,layoutheight = 566.36717pt,left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm, bottom=0mm,footskip=1mm}
    EXPECTING SAME POTRAIT

\end{document}
```

Comment: There is a »r‹ missing in your option: you have to use `paper=portrait` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding option `paper` there was a change in KOMA-Script version 3.22: Now  it depends on the orientation (`portrait` or `landscape`) which value is taken as the height and which as the width.

With `paper = landscape`, both paper=`566.36717pt:432pt` and paper=`432pt:566.36717pt` result in a page with a height of 432pt and a width of 566.36717pt. If you want to switch to portrait, you have to add `paper=portrait` explicitly:

```latex
\documentclass[usegeometry]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\begin{document}
\KOMAoptions{paper=432pt:566.36717pt}
\recalctypearea
\newgeometry{margin=0mm,footskip=1mm}
POTRAIT

\KOMAoptions{paper=432pt:226.15027pt,paper=landscape}
\recalctypearea
\newgeometry{margin=0mm,footskip=1mm}
LANDSCAPE

\KOMAoptions{paper=432pt:566.36717pt,
  paper=portrait% <- added
}
\recalctypearea
\newgeometry{margin=0pt,footskip=1mm}
EXPECTING SAME SIZE AND ORIENTATION (POTRAIT) AS FIRST PAGE, BUT DOES NOT WORK
\end{document}
```

[image]

Additional remark: I would suggest to use class option `usegeometry`.

Comment: Can you check my edited question. I am using almost the same code as yours but give me an error `! Package scrbase Error: unknown option paper=potrait'.` thats the reason why i was using `version=3.21` thing.

Comment: Oh got it, its a spelling mistake `potrait` vs `portrait`