How to rotate some pages of the document with normal geometry and the page number in the correct direction?
When I edit my docs, I encounter the problem that I want to change some pages in the middle of my docs.
Just like this(The pages in pdf-reader is rotate, but the pagefooter didn't shift):

I posted the result I achieve use MSoffice-word as below:

The requirement as follows:

The First two pages placed normally forward, while the next two(or more) page is horizontally placed, then the last pages return to be normally placement.(i.e. I want to change the pages in the middle part of the docs)
The geometry of the landscape pages should be the same as the normal page(which confused me a lot in my attempt shown below)
The pageheader and the pagefooter should also be rotated
The page in the pdf-reader could be rotated automatically with the code compiled(no need for my manually rotate the page in pdf-editor)
It can work with xelatex on Windows and it support the ctex fonts.

Here below is my attempt but finally it couldn't meet my necessity.
[My First Attempt——just use 'landscape' environment, but the third page didn't rotate in pdf-reader(the blue box), and the page number didn't rotate(the red box)]
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{ctexart}
\usepackage[left=22mm,top=15mm,right=22mm,bottom=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs} 
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{zhlipsum}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\zhlipsum[4-5]
\lipsum[3-6]
\clearpage
\begin{landscape}
    这是一页横向的表格\\
    \begin{table}[htbp]
        \centering
        \begin{tblr}{
                hlines,vlines,
                columns    = {18mm,c},
            }
            \toprule
            Category & \SetCell[c=9]{c} Number                                 \\
            \midrule
            1        & 1                       & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
            2        & 2                       & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\
            3        & 3                       & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 \\
            4        & 4                       & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 \\
            5        & 5                       & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 \\
            6        & 6                       & 6 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 6 \\
            7        & 7                       & 7 & 7 & 7 & 7 & 7 & 7 & 7 & 7 \\
            8        & 8                       & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tblr}
        \caption{A Table with Random Numbers}
        \label{tab:random-table}
    \end{table}
\end{landscape}
\zhlipsum[4-5]
\lipsum[3-6]
\end{document}

Then I get this:

[My second attempt] refer the link with the package typearea:
\documentclass[12pt]{ctexart}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[paper=portrait,pagesize]{typearea}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{zhlipsum}
\begin{document}
\section{This is my Portrait Page}
\lipsum[2-4]
\newpage
\KOMAoptions{paper=landscape,pagesize}
\recalctypearea
\section{This is my Landscape Page}
Text in my landscape section\footnote{Footnote in Landscape}
\zhlipsum[8-9]
\newpage
\KOMAoptions{paper=portrait,pagesize}
\recalctypearea
\section{This is again Portrait Page}
\lipsum[10]

\end{document}

But the code failed when I insert more than one page of the landsacpe page.(The red box shows the correct direction of the page number, while the width of the landscape page is too narrow in the doc, while I only want to set the margin=2cm as the normal page)

[My Thire Attempt] refer to the same linkenter link description here by resetting the config of fancyhdr.
My code is as below:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ctex}
\usepackage[margin=5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{zhlipsum}

\fancypagestyle{mylandscape}{
\fancyhf{} %Clears the header/footer
\fancyfoot{% Footer
\makebox[\textwidth][r]{% Right
  \rlap{\hspace{.75cm}% Push out of margin by \footskip
    \smash{% Remove vertical height
      \raisebox{4.87in}{% Raise vertically
        \rotatebox{90}{\thepage}}}}}}% Rotate counter-clockwise
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% No header rule
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% No footer rule
}
%%%% Now the actual Document %%%%
\begin{document}
\lipsum[3-8]
\zhlipsum[2]
\clearpage
% When you need landscape page do this
\begin{landscape}
  \thispagestyle{mylandscape} %Call our predefined page type

  \zhlipsum[3]
  \lipsum[10-12]
  %End lanscape to go back to portrait
\end{landscape}
\zhlipsum[5]
\lipsum[3-8]
\clearpage
\end{document}

After that I get the rotate pages(the fourth and fifth) in pdf-editor, but, if I change the parameter "margin"(just set 5cm) of geometry, the fourth page number didn't appear in the middle as I want, and the second page(the fifth), the page number didn't rotate. All the solution I found failed!

I really confusing and exhausting after attempting and searching! Looking forward to yr birlliant answer!

your requirements are impossible. You can't get "the same geometry on the landscape pages". For example the linewidth is different, and you also want a much wider header box. You want two different geometries. So at first build two documents, one portrait, one landscape to get the geometries right. Once you really know what you want on the landscape pages you can then try to set it up. Alternatively use pagestyle empty on the landscape pages then nobody sees the page number. Or redesign your table so that it fits on a portrait page.

However, could I change the geometry of the landscape page not too narrow as the second attempt? it really looks bad for the narrow geometry, and  I couldn't believe that no other LaTeX users hold similar requirements it can be configured via MSoffice word or others.

I posted the result via MSoffice-word to set the same geometry with landscape one, to better illsturate my requiremnts. Thanks!

see here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/527031/2388 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/556997/2388

not all pdf viewers honour the rotation, so even if it rotates correctly for you, it may not elsewhere. I take it this document will never be printed? B/c it will look very odd if the header and footer are rotated. Not rotating them is deliberate because the aim is to produce a document which can be printed. unless this is an institutional requirement (which are often bonkers and almost always immutable), have a think about what really makes sense here. Don't assume word is giving you something sensible.
